# I am using linq datasource, how can i configure a where expression

Tags: c#, linqdatasource

RequestDate != @RequestDate = null

Gives me an ERROR:
The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: What language are you using here?

Comment: I am trying to load data that RequestDate has null value and I am using C#.

Comment: Please modify the question, and provide more context/code.

Comment: I need to put a where clause statement inside linq datasource and I got RequestDate != @RequestDate = null but it's giving an error.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring your Where expression, you should add to the WhereParameters collection like so:

```
                    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSourceDivisionMemberships" runat="server" 
                        ContextTypeName="NYDERHE.NYDERHEDataClassesDataContext" EnableDelete="True" 
                        EnableInsert="True" TableName="DivisionMemberships" 
                        Where="FacultyMemberID == @FacultyMemberID">
                        <WhereParameters>
                            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hdnFacultyMemberID" Name="FacultyMemberID" 
                                PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
                        </WhereParameters>
                    </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

In addition to ControlParameters, there are QueryStringParameters, just plain Parameters (which you often set in the code-behind or leave as their default value), and more.

Answer (score 0):

In reponse to:

> I am trying to load data that RequestDate has null value and I am using C#

Why not use

```
Where = "RequestDate == null"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select records where RequestDate is null
then what about

```
 from r in table where ! r.RequestDate.HasValue select r
```